# name for lesson when teacher is absent

Tags: single-word-requests

When a teacher is absent because of a sudden illness or something else that is unforeseen and children haven't got a lesson of some subject; is there a name for such a lesson?

Comment: What do the children actually do during that time? Work quietly by themselves? Trash the classroom? Or are you looking for a word which describes an unsupervised class no matter what they are actually doing?

Comment: If old enough to be left unattended, it will be called a free period or self study.

Comment: It's up to the school authorities (and whatever preplanning they have done) to decide whether it's recess, study period, library visit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of words that might apply to this situation:

- *improvised* or *impromptu* or *unplanned* is for when the students haven't been given work for this lesson and someone quickly thinks up work for them to do. There are plenty of other synonyms.
- *substitute lesson* or *alternative lesson* can be used for when the students are given other work instead of the work they were supposed to do
- *free period* or *free lesson* for if they are given no work and are allowed to choose what they do.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmmm, methinks 'busywork' as a possibility. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busywork)

Certainly, 'substitution' fits the circumstance.